# Upload image after choosing filter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, filter

he i have here a script where users can choose a filder, but how can i make it when they are done with choosing a filder that the script sends the picture to a php script so that i can upload on the server?

```
$(function() {

    /*
        In this code, we are going to do the following:

        1. Accept an image on drag and drop
        2. Create a new canvas element (original), with a max size
           of 500x500px (customizable) and keep it in memory
        3. Listen for clicks on the filters. When one is selected:
                3.1 Create a clone of the original canvas
                3.2 Remove any canvas elements currently on the page
                3.3 Append the clone to the #photo div
                3.4 If the selected filter is different from the "Normal"
                    one, call the Caman library. Otherwise do nothing.
                3.5 Mark the selected filter with the "active" class
        4. Trigger the "Normal" filter

    */

    var maxWidth = 500,
        maxHeight = 500,
        photo = $('#photo'),
        originalCanvas = null,
        filters = $('#filters li a'),
        filterContainer = $('#filterContainer');

    // Use the fileReader plugin to listen for
    // file drag and drop on the photo div:

    photo.fileReaderJS({
        on:{
            load: function(e, file){

                // An image has been dropped.

                var img = $('<img>').appendTo(photo),
                    imgWidth, newWidth,
                    imgHeight, newHeight,
                    ratio;

                // Remove canvas elements left on the page
                // from previous image drag/drops.

                photo.find('canvas').remove();
                filters.removeClass('active');

                // When the image is loaded successfully,
                // we can find out its width/height:

                img.load(function() {

                    imgWidth  = this.width;
                    imgHeight = this.height;

                    // Calculate the new image dimensions, so they fit
                    // inside the maxWidth x maxHeight bounding box

                    if (imgWidth >= maxWidth || imgHeight >= maxHeight) {

                        // The image is too large,
                        // resize it to fit a 500x500 square!

                        if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {

                            // Wide
                            ratio = imgWidth / maxWidth;
                            newWidth = maxWidth;
                            newHeight = imgHeight / ratio;

                        } else {

                            // Tall or square
                            ratio = imgHeight / maxHeight;
                            newHeight = maxHeight;
                            newWidth = imgWidth / ratio;

                        }

                    } else {
                        newHeight = imgHeight;
                        newWidth = imgWidth;
                    }

                    // Create the original canvas.

                    originalCanvas = $('<canvas>');
                    var originalContext = originalCanvas[0].getContext('2d');

                    // Set the attributes for centering the canvas

                    originalCanvas.attr({
                        width: newWidth,
                        height: newHeight
                    }).css({
                        marginTop: -newHeight/2,
                        marginLeft: -newWidth/2
                    });

                    // Draw the dropped image to the canvas
                    // with the new dimensions
                    originalContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

                    // We don't need this any more
                    img.remove();

                    filterContainer.fadeIn();

                    // Trigger the default "normal" filter
                    filters.first().click();
                });

                // Set the src of the img, which will
                // trigger the load event when done:

                img.attr('src', e.target.result);
            },

            beforestart: function(file){

                // Accept only images.
                // Returning false will reject the file.

                return /^image/.test(file.type);
            }
        }
    });

    // Listen for clicks on the filters

    filters.click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var f = $(this);

        if(f.is('.active')){
            // Apply filters only once
            return false;
        }

        filters.removeClass('active');
        f.addClass('active');

        // Clone the canvas
        var clone = originalCanvas.clone();

        // Clone the image stored in the canvas as well
        clone[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(originalCanvas[0],0,0);


        // Add the clone to the page and trigger
        // the Caman library on it

        photo.find('canvas').remove().end().append(clone);

        var effect = $.trim(f[0].id);

        Caman(clone[0], function () {

            // If such an effect exists, use it:

            if( effect in this){
                this[effect]();
                this.render();

                // Show the download button
                showDownload(clone[0]);
            }
            else{
                hideDownload();
            }
        });

    });

    // Use the mousewheel plugin to scroll
    // scroll the div more intuitively

    filterContainer.find('ul').on('mousewheel',function(e, delta){

        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
        e.preventDefault();

    });

    var downloadImage = $('a.downloadImage');

    function showDownload(canvas){


        downloadImage.off('click').click(function(){

            // When the download link is clicked, get the
            // DataURL of the image and set it as href:

            var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
            downloadImage.attr('href', url);

        }).fadeIn();

    }

    function hideDownload(){
        downloadImage.fadeOut();
    }

});
```

Comment: `... picture true a php script..`? "through"?

Comment: yes i want to choose the filter than upload  
through php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what kinds of questions to ask here. In general, we like it when you narrow down your issue to a single, specific problem and a small block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

[HTML5 Drag and Drop Uploader - http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)